# Visual basic (Of T, or Of V)

Tags: vb.net

When creating classes or other elements in VB.NET, for example :

```
Public Class Class1(Of T)

End Class
```

What does "(Of T )" mean in this code ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Of T)` is a generic type parameter. It means that you can:

- Refer to T in the class code, without knowing the type of T.
- Construct instances of class `Class1`, passing any Type T into it.

This is used to construct classes, that can operate on different types, without knowing the type at compile time. This is, among other things, very useful for collection classes, where you are able to create the collection once (Example: List), and then create a `List (Of String)` or `List(Of DateTime)` and so on, for any specific type you might need.

Also, see [this MSDN article on generics in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It means type parameter, it means that this class is capable of working with objects of a class that you specify during creation. For example `List (Of T)`.