# VB Syntax of Baseclass Inheritance

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I am wondering what the following snippets code means.  Specifically the section: "Of EntityType As {BusinessEntity, New})".  I'm a little new to VB inheritance so some of the syntax is a little foregn to me.  I understand that a base class is being used to add functionality to all business objects that inherit from it but the syntax is throwing me off a bit.  Is there a name for this design pattern?

```
Public Class AppObjectBase(Of EntityType As {BusinessEntity, New})
    Inherits BusinessObject(Of EntityType)
...
...

Public Class NavTreeObj
    Inherits NavTree(Of NavTreeEntity)
End Class

Public Class NavTree(Of EntityType As {NavTreeEntity, New})
    Inherits AppObjectBase(Of EntityType)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual basic (Of T, or Of V)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601868/visual-basic-of-t-or-of-v)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I believe that this question stands apart since although it is referring to generic programming, I was uncertain as to what {BusinessEntity, New} actually means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what the `Of EntityType` part on its own means?  If not then you should read about generic types.  As for the `As {BusinessEntity, New}` part, that means that `EntityType` must either be or inherit from the `BusinessEntity` type and it must also have a parameterless constructor.  By specifying those constraints on the generic type parameter, you are able to access members of the `BusinessEntity` type and also invoke the constructor to create new instances within the method.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney, I am familiar with generic programming so your answer makes sense to me.